# Is there a way to override a c# enum?

Tags: c#, enums

My C# system processes payment information from several customers that submit a text file to us using various formats. They all have common information such as PaymentDate, Amount, CheckNumber, etc.

I would love to set up a generic enum that is overridden based on the customer. For example:

```
private enum Payment { PaymentDate, Amount, CheckNumber }
private enum CustomerA { CheckNumber, Amount, PaymentDate }
private enum CustomerB { Amount, PaymentDate, CheckNumber }
```

It would be nice if I could then assign the layout depending on the Customer.

```
Payment = CustomerA; 
Payment = CustomerB;
```

Then I could reference the fields such as:

```
var checkNumber = line[(int) Payment.CheckNumber];
var PaymentDate = line[(int) Payment.PaymentDate];
```

etc.

Each line would know it's own format.

Is there a way to do this in C#?

Comment: No, there is no way to do that only with enums.

Comment: This looks like an attempt to drastically overcomplicate a much simpler problem.  But you're not asking about the simpler problem, you're asking how to force your over-complicated attempt to solve it.  So we can't really help with the simpler problem.  Even if you find a way to make this work, I wouldn't want to imagine what that code looks like or how difficult it would be to support it.  If your customers have different data formats, why not just write objects which convert between their individual formats and your common standard format?  Convert on input and output.

Comment: You wouldn't want to program a customers data like that would you? Seems like there would be a better way to think about the problem you have.

Comment: Seems like it would be better to put information about how to parse these files into configuration files.  Then on-boarding a new customer shouldn't require a code change.

Comment: This looks like a misuse of enums in the first place. Not sure an enum is even relevant in this situation. Perhaps this question makes more sense if `Payment` is a class with those properties?

Comment: You could create an interface IPayment with getter properties for the values then create classes for your customer types that implement the interface, returning the appropriate offsets.

Comment: If there is a specific limited set of such properties you want to support, and each customer uses its own numbers for the different types, I advice just making a mapping in a config file for that.

Answer (score 0):

No, you cannot override enums. They are compile time constants.

I recommend taking a step back and rethinking this because it's easy to over engineer an idea and I believe you're doing that. There are similar ways to do what you're attempting.

You can compare enum values but that's not you're question and it's not worth it to confuse it further by example. Just a suggestion... In my opinion and experience I recommending a different approach altogether and believe you'll be happier you did.  I know I've chased ideas into days of work only to realize I could have done it another way later and it was so much simpler the other way.